# With PHP to MySQL datetime formatting

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I am trying to convert `$dt = "Tue May 15 00:09:06 UTC+0100 2012"` into a `datetime` field of MySQL database server, but the entered value is always 6 hours behind.

My server is in Dallas, US and I am in UK.

Any ideas how to resolve this?

Comment: Seems like you just answered your own question. The database is most likely returning the date in the local timezone.

Comment: "Any ideas how to resolve this?" -- add 6 hours to each datetime from the db?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without more information (some code, for example), it's difficult to debug, but given the variable you *did* provide, this snippet may work:

```
<?php
$dt_for_db = gmdate("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($dt));
```

Then, every time you pull from the database, be sure to append `GMT` (there's a space at the beginning) to *every* date.

```
<?php
$dt_from_db = $dt_from_db.' GMT';
```

Basically, dates in MySQL `datetime` columns do *not* store timezone information, so you have to be sure to always know what timezone you're using (UTC/GMT). Then, append that timezone to the end of each date you pull from the database before using any `date` functions on it (as `date` functions assume local time for dates without a timezone specified).

Comment: this is the datetime i am passing "Tue May 1 20:46:43 UTC+0100 2012". and this is what is inserted into database table "2012-05-01 19:46:43" code i am using os here gmdate('Y-m-d H:i:s O', strtotime($_POST["hdn_step3_date_time"]));

Comment: @JagjotSingh, I'd suggest formatting the date before inserting it into the database, so you have full control over what is inserted (first snippet in my answer).

Comment: @JagjotSingh, `$dt_from_db` is one hour behind? Or the date inserted into the database is one hour behind?

Comment: @JagjotSingh, would that be because of your `+0100` (+1 hour offset)?

Comment: I tried to change this value "17-May-2012 @ 23:49".

Using your code gmdate("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($_POST["hdn_step2a_date_time"])); like this and this is what i got "17-May-2012 22:49:00".

Its 1 hours less.

Comment: @JagjotSingh, that sounds like the timezone set on your server is 1 hour away from GMT. It's *supposed* to change the date, if the date provided is local time (as your example is). *How* much it changes depends on which timezone is set for the server. For example, every local date I put in for my server would have a 5-hour or 4-hour difference (depending on whether it's DST or not). If you don't want it to change, simply set the timezone of the provided date to `GMT`.

Comment: @JagjotSingh, you can get the default timezone with `<?php echo date_default_timezone_get(); ?>`

Comment: This is what they said: what you will likely want to do is set the default timezone in which you'd like the date to be set as; once it's set, you can go ahead and insert the date. You will want to look at the date_default_timezone_set() function; more information on that here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php
 
You could also do all the converting in MySQL alone, instead of trying to convert the date with PHP, such as "select timediff(now(),convert_tz(now(),@@session.time_zone,'+00:00'));".

Comment: @JagjotSingh, while this *works* specifically for getting the "correct" date into the database, it makes it necessary to explicitly specify the timezone to display a date in *every* time you display it. It also increases the load on MySQL as you are converting the date every time you read it (which, in most cases, is completely unnecessary). On top of that, **MySQL uses a different default timezone than PHP**.

Answer (score 1):

use

```
 date_default_timezone_set("America/New_York");
```

replacing "America/New_York" to the code for London to shift your servers timezone to the proper GMT timezone.  You can look up the proper code on php.net if you look for timezone stuff.

Just place it at the top of each page that you use dates and then use php DateTime objects with the ->format('c') function.

You can also set timezone information in your php.ini file if you have access to it.

-Jordan

Comment: I wouldn't recommend this option as it will change the date displayed to end users to GMT, instead of local time. Yes, it's less work now, but if you ever decide that you want to display a different timezone by default, or allow users to override the setting, this will cause more of a headache than it's worth.